# Excel, extract duplicates from multiple columns

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, duplicates, extract

Is there a way to extract the duplicates from 3 different columns?
Let's say I have

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
ID1       ID4       ID7
ID2       ID5       ID8  
ID3       ID6       ID9    
ID98      ID98      ID98
ID99      ID99      ID99
```

I would like to create a fourth column where I only see the value that are duplicated in each of the 3 columns, to obtain

```
Column D
ID98
ID99
```

Is there an easy way to do it in Excel/VBA?

I tried to copy multiple formulas but was not able to find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unique in 3 Columns

This will return all values that occur at least once in each column.

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP(A2:A6,B2:B6,B2:B6),C2:C6,C2:C6),3))
```

[image]

To make it flexible, to work for any (reasonable) number of columns, you could use...

```
=LET(data,A2:C6,
    f,TAKE(data,,1),
    o,DROP(data,,1),
    rs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0),
    cs,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(o)),
    c,REDUCE(rs,cs,LAMBDA(rr,c,
        rr*ISNUMBER(XMATCH(f,CHOOSECOLS(o,c))))),
    dr,UNIQUE(FILTER(f,c)),
dr)
```

... which would, after removing the 'redundant' variables, result in the following:

```
=LET(data,A2:C6,
    f,TAKE(data,,1),
    o,DROP(data,,1),
UNIQUE(FILTER(f,REDUCE(
    SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0),
    SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(o)),LAMBDA(rr,c,
    rr*ISNUMBER(XMATCH(f,CHOOSECOLS(o,c))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try:

```
=LET(
    d, $A$2:$A$6,
    FILTER(
        d,
        BYROW(d, LAMBDA(arr, COUNTIFS($A$2:$C$6, arr) = 3))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(COUNTIFS(A2:C6,A2:C6)>1,A2:C6),2))
```

---

Or, use within <kbd>LET()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A2:C6,
     UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(COUNTIFS(α,α)>1,α),2)))
```

---

If as per your OP

> *I would like to create a fourth column where I only see the value that are duplicated in each of the 3 columns, to obtain*

means to get the duplicate values across three different columns then you can use the following formula.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A2:C6,
     φ, BYROW(α,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(MMULT(N(x=TRANSPOSE(x)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(x),,,0))>1))=3)),
     UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(φ,α),3)))
```

---

If there are always three columns, then in place of this `SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(x),,,0)` we can use `{1;1;1}`

```
=LET(
     α, A2:C6,
     φ, BYROW(α,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(MMULT(N(x=TRANSPOSE(x)),{1;1;1})>1))=3)),
     UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(φ,α),3)))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you mean to get the values where that value in each 3 columns is the same in the same row, or simply the values that are not distinct uniques. If you mean the latter, you could use Mayukhs or VBasic2008's answer. else:

`=UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER(A1:C5,MMULT(N(A1:A5=A1:C5),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C5),,,0))=3)))`

Answer (score 2):

If your data is that simple, you can hardcode the 3 using `COUNTIF()`:

```
=FILTER(C1:C5,COUNTIF(A1:C5,C1:C5)=3)
```

This would also work if some column is different in length as long as you include empty cells in the range too. Values also don't need to be in the same line, however I did assume there are **no** duplicates within the same column.